# Subquery unnesting oracle in case of analytical function

Tags: oracle11g

I have an oracle query with subquery . The subquery uses an analytical function. If the subquery is changed to join, then there is a signification improvement in execution time. But in same other similar queries it remains the same. On looking at the explain plan, i was able to find that subquery which showed significant improvement had changed to  join automatically by Oracle optimizer.

When i searched for the concept of unnesting subquery, which basically means converting the subquery into joins, it mentions under certain conditions, this happens.

https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/entry/optimizer_transformations_subquery_unesting_part_1

What is not clear to me is from the explain plan, how to understand it executes multiple times

```
Query Synopsis:
 JOIN CONTRACT CONTRACT
  ON UWFILE.ID         =CONTRACT.UWFILE_ID
  AND CONTRACT.YEAR    = UWFILE.YEAR
  AND UWFILE.ORDER_NUM = CONTRACT.ORDER_NUM
  AND CONTRACT.ID     IN
    (SELECT ID
    FROM
      (SELECT ID,
        DENSE_RANK()over(partition BY CONTRACT.FACUL_NUM, CONTRACT.YEAR order by (CONTRACT.ENDOR_NUM) DESC) AS endor_rank
      FROM CONTRACT
      )
    WHERE endor_rank = 1
    )

Explain plan Synopsis:

Filter Predicates 
AND  CONTRACT.LAST_IN_FORCE=1                        

  EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM (SELECT ID ID,DENSE_RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY CONTRACT.FACUL_NUM,CONTRACT.YEAR ORDER BY INTERNAL_FUNCTION(CONTRACT.ENDOR_NUM) DESC  
VIEW  
   Filter Predicates  
   AND  

  ID=:B1  
  ENDOR_RANK=1 
 WINDOW  Filter Predicates DENSE_RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY CONTRACT.FACUL_NUM,CONTRACT.YEAR ORDER BY INTERNAL_FUNCTION(CONTRACT.ENDOR_NUM) DESC )<=1
```

Comment: Please show queries and explain plan.

Comment: Added the synopsis of query and explain plan. This subquery seems to be non unnested and seems to repeat. i am not clear, when it unnests the subquery